# In plot(allEffects) of the 'effect's package in R: how to remove the lines connecting levels of a categorical variable?

Tags: r, effects

I am using a lot of plots made with the `effects` package.
By reading the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/effects/vignettes/predictor-effects-gallery.pdf), I do find a lot of ways to customize the plots, including `multiline = TRUE`.
However, nothing is mentioned about how to get rid of the lines connecting levels of a categorical variable that are displayed here:

[image]

I do not understand why they are here in the first place actually.
I have also tried to plot with the following code:

```
p <- predictorEffects(M1)

plot(p, PexCP$treatment, 
    main=paste(effect, "effect plot"),
    symbols=TRUE, lines=FALSE)
```

which fails

> Error in x[[selection]] : recursive indexing failed at level 3

From the vignette,data and code:

```
library(effects)
library(car) 
Prestige$type <- factor(Prestige$type, levels=c("bc", "wc", "prof")) 
lm1 <- lm(prestige ~ education + poly(women, 2) + + log(income)*type, data=Prestige)
e3.lm1 <- predictorEffect("type", lm1)
plot(e3.lm1, lines = list(multiline = FALSE))
```

Comment: Take care of reproducibility. Provide sample data.

Comment: try `plot(p, ..., lty = 0)`, this sets the line type to "blank"

Comment: It worked ! Thank you !